# Accessing object properties in listener method

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var Obj = function() {
   this.property = 1;
   this.arr = [...] // array containing elements we want to add event listeners to
   for (...) {
      this.arr[i].addEventListener("click", this.listener, false);
   }
}

Obj.prototype.listener = function() {
   console.log( this.property ); // DOES NOT WORK! *this* does not point to Obj.
}
var a = new Obj();
```

How do I access object properties (and methods) within a listener? I would assume I'd need to pass it as a parameter? Is the way I'm going about this structurally wrong?

Comment: `this.listener.bind(this)`

Comment: Might be helpful to understand whats going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function is called as an event listener, the context (`this`) is changed to something other that the object itself.

---

To resolve this, manually bind the context to the object instance in the constructor using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). This way, `this` will always point to the object instance, independent of the calling context:

```js
var Obj = function() {
  this.property = 'foo';
  this.listener = this.listener.bind(this);
}

Obj.prototype.listener = function() {
  console.log(this.property);
}

var a = new Obj();
a.listener.call({});
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Tushar, you can use `Function.prototype.bind()` and pass `this.property` as parameter

```html
<body>
  click
  <script>
    var Obj = function() {
        var obj = this;
        this.property = 1;
        this.arr = [document.body];
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.arr.length; i++) {
          obj.arr[i].addEventListener("click"
          , obj.listener.bind(obj.arr[i], obj.property), false);
        }
      }
    // note order of parameters; e.g., `prop`, `e`
    Obj.prototype.listener = function(prop, e) {
      console.log(prop, e); // `1`, `event` object
    }
    var a = new Obj();
  </script>
</body>
```